# How does one create multiple instances of filepicker (each one using a different account) on one page?

Tags: multiple-instances, filepicker, filepicker.io

I have a JS library that uses filepicker to upload files to our service. We have a customer who is already a filepicker customer (using it on his site). When he embeds our JS library our instance of filepicker collides with his.

How does one create multiple instances of filepicker (each one using a different account) on one page?